# How to use multiple columns as the frame of an animation in gganimate package (R)?

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, visualization, gganimate

I am trying to use *gganimate* package of R, to create an animation of a bunch of histograms, where each frame of the animation shows a histogram of an image. I have ~400 images, so ~400 columns. My data looks like this:

```
| bins.left | bins.right | hist1 | hist 2 | ... | hist n |
```

and as you see, I need each column be considered as the Y value of the histogram, in each frame. In other words, my animation should iterate over the columns.

But all the examples that I have studied on the Internet, seem to be considering only one column as the identifier of the frames. For instance in [this example](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/16-r-packages/58-gganimate-create-animations-with-ggplot2/):

```
mapping <- aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp, 
           size = pop, color = continent,
           frame = year) 
p <- ggplot(gapminder, mapping = mapping) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10()
```

the attribute '*Year*' is considered as the iterator. This data looks like this:

```
  country continent  year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap
   <fctr>    <fctr> <int>   <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>
1 Afghanistan      Asia  1952  28.801  8425333  779.4453
2 Afghanistan      Asia  1957  30.332  9240934  820.8530
3 Afghanistan      Asia  1962  31.997 10267083  853.1007
4 Afghanistan      Asia  1967  34.020 11537966  836.1971
5 Afghanistan      Asia  1972  36.088 13079460  739.9811
6 Afghanistan      Asia  1977  38.438 14880372  786.1134
```

The reason that I don't want to modify my data to fit into such a pattern is that if I keep all the histograms in one column, my data frame will be extremely lengthy (length = ~ 16000 * 400) and difficult to handle. In addition, it is not intuitive to keep my data in such a confusing fashion. I believe there must be an easy solution to my problem. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: You say you have ~400 images. Do you mean 400 data frames that you want to turn into histograms?  Please post an actual sample of your data using `dput` (for example, paste into your question the output of `dput(my_data[1:10, ])`.

Comment: Most tools in R assume your data is *long* rather than *wide*, and therefore data is generally *easier* to work with in long format. Either way you have the same total number of cells, so I'm not sure I understand your concerns about reshaping the data.

Comment: @Marius, this form of data is not easy to view and avoid some potential mistakes. And it seems natural to keep time series each in a separate column. I don't want to reshape my data simply because I don't know how to make it work in gganimate. But if it is not possible, then I will have to reshape it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Marius said, you can make this work if your data is in long format. Below I create some fake data and then make the animated plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_classic())
library(gganimate)
```

Here's fake data with 10 columns of values we want to turn into histograms.

```
set.seed(2)
dat = replicate(10, runif(100)) %>% as.data.frame
```

The data is in wide format, so first we'll convert it to long format with the `gather` function:

```
d = dat %>% gather(key, value)
```

In the new long format, the `key` column tells us which histogram column the data originally came from. We'll use this as our `frame` and run `geom_histogram`:

```
p = ggplot(d, aes(value, frame=key)) +
  geom_histogram() 

gganimate(p)
```

You can see that this is not what we want. `ggplot` actually generated a single histogram from all the data and the animation just shows us in succession the part of each stack that came from each value of `key`.

[image]

We need a way to get ggplot to create separate histograms and animate them. We can do that by pre-binning the data and using `geom_rect` to create the histogram bars:

```
d = dat %>% gather(key, value) %>% 
  mutate(bins = cut(value, breaks=seq(0,1,0.1), 
                    labels=seq(0,0.9,0.1) + 0.05, include.lowest=TRUE),
         bins = as.numeric(as.character(bins))) %>% 
  group_by(key, bins) %>% 
  tally

p = ggplot(d, aes(xmin=bins - 0.048, xmax=bins + 0.048, ymin=0, ymax=n, frame=key)) +
  geom_rect() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max(d$n)))

gganimate(p)
```

[image]

In response to your comment, I don't think you can use `gganimate` with data in wide format. `gganimate` requires a single `frame` column, which requires data in long format. However, `gganimate` is a wrapper around the `animation` package, and you can create an animated GIF file directly with a for loop and the `saveGIF` function:

```
library(animation)

saveGIF({
  for (i in names(dat)) {
    p = ggplot(dat, aes_string(i)) +
      geom_histogram(breaks=seq(0,1,0.1))
    print(p)
  }
}, movie.name="test.gif")
```

[image]

Comment: eipi10, thank you very much. This definitely resolves my issue. Before I mark this as the answer, allow me to wait for a while to see if someone could suggest a way that works without putting all the time series end to end in one column. Thanks again.

Comment: See update to my answer for a different method that allows you to keep your data in wide format.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer.